# How to sort rows in JTable based on object property?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am having a JTable with `Cat`objects. I am displaying their names. How can I when I click on  the table header sort by another criteria than their textual name? I have a sort column in the database that I want to use instead. I have tried overriding the `getColumnClass` method of the DefaultTableModel but it seems wrong. What can I use?

Comment: Have you checked out [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) section from How to use Tables?

Comment: *"I have a sort column in the database that I want to use instead."*  What logic does it use to determine the order?

Comment: I am displaying their names. == override String.Class in getColumnClass, or is there another reason why trying to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have two columns in the database: Name and Sort. E.g. 'Simpson', 1; 'Albert', 2. Where the first is the name and the second is an integer representing the sort.

Comment: @MadProgrammer And yes, I have checked it.

Comment: `And yes, I have checked it` - so if you followed the examples in the tutorial, then your code should work. We are not mind readers, we can't guess what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches suggest themselves:

- Let `Cat` implement `Comparable<Cat>`, as shown in this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).
- Supply a suitable `Comparator` to your `RowSorter`, as shown in [*Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

I either case, you can delegate, as `name` is likely a `String`, which already implements `Comparable<String>`.